# Relay email for some addresses to a different server

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to configure postfix to relay email to a new server for only some addresses without changing the address.

I'm testing a new email server (in this case, Office365). I want to test with a user user@example.com who is currently receiving email locally.  I want to configure postfix to send user@thursby.com email to example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com without changing the address (user@example.com).  I want to do this to verify delivery before changing the MX record for the domain example.com.

**EDIT**

Thank you for pointing me to the same question asked previously.  Given that information, I was able to figure out the steps.  Here's what I did:

- Edit the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
- Add the following line near TRANSPORT MAP:

`transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport`

- Run "postfix reload" to take new setting.
- Edit the file `/etc/postfix/transport`
- Add the following line:

`username@domain.com  smtp:domain.mail.protection.outlook.com:25`

- Run "postmap /etc/postfix/transport" to create the hash.
- Verify that the solution work.